# Non-existent sub domains resolving to primary domain

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have run into something I find odd. I am using Apache/2.0.54

If I try to access a non existent sub domain on my server it will resolve to the primary domain. For example going to

```
http://www.fakesub.mydomain.com
```

will resolve to http://www.mydomain.com .

If I enter a valid subdomain e.g.

```
http://www.validsub.mydomain.com
```

it **will** resolve to the proper sub domain.

I am thinking this is due to a server confg of some kind but I'm not sure what. Googling didn't really help me but that may be because I don't know what to call this exactly.

Could anyone suggest why this is happening? Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a `NameVirtualHost` enabled address/port combination, the first matching `<VirtualHost>` to load is considered the default; requests that match no other hosts are sent to it.  See your current configuration with `apache2ctl -S`.

If you want to avoid this behavior, make the first to load a dummy vhost which serves no content.